# Why are setTimeout and setInterval working differently in the browser and in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, settimeout, setinterval

```js
let cnt=0;

let i = setInterval(() => {
  console.log(cnt++);
},200)

setTimeout(() => {
  clearInterval(i);
},2000);
```

When executed in browser this code logs:-
`0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`

But when executed using Node it logs:-
`0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8`

What is the reason for this?

Comment: what is the value of cnt?, please update your post with the value

Comment: @EJBEAN the cnt is initialised to 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because Chrome [does self-correct the drift](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:third_party/WebKit/Source/platform/Timer.cpp;drc=e6d900fb6ed08dbd3a048899f38962ee75f4d8d0;l=162) in `setInterval`. node (and other browsers) don't. Note that currently specs agree with node, even if there is an [active discussion](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/3151) to follow Chrome's behavior.

So in Chrome, it's like if you had a precise

```
at beginTime + 200
  do fn
at beginTime + 400
  do fn
at beginTime + 600
  do fn
...etc
```

while in others it will be

```
at beginTime + 200
  do fn
  at now + 200
    do fn
    ...etc.
```

But we know there will always be some delay preventing the timer to fire exactly when scheduled, and so in environments without drift correction, we end up with a `now` that is later the expected time.

So in Chrome, the `setInterval` job will be in the queue before the `setTimeout` one, while in other environments, it will come after, because of the drift, even if infinitesimally small.

Comment: I understand it now. Thanks for your answer. Appreciate it.